# LDAP/AD: How to get username or user with samaccountname?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I started to use the unboundid SDK to connect and work with LDAP/AD. With the `WhoAmIExtendedRequest` i can get the samaccountname. But who can i get the user and the full username? Is there an other request or a DN?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: WhoAmIExtendedResult whoAmIResult = (WhoAmIExtendedResult)
                            ldap.processExtendedOperation(new WhoAmIExtendedRequest());

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When a result (i.e., a `WhoAmIExtendedResult`) is obtained from Active Directory, you should be able to use the `WhoAmIExtendedResult.getAuthorizationID()` method to obtain the DN of the authenticated user. An example is described in the [Javadoc](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/extensions/WhoAmIExtendedRequest.html) for the class, but the authorization ID returned by the AD server could take one of the following forms:

- `dn: uid=username,ou=clients,dc=example,dc=com`
- `u: uid=username`
- The empty string or just "`dn:`", indicating an anonymous bind.